# MATLAB: Can't convert cell array vector to numeric array vector

Tags: matlab

Here is the code:

```
>> fid = fopen('dump.dat');
>> line_ex = fgetl(fid)

line_ex =

    '106,94,241,11,190,237,209,224'

>> newStr = split(line_ex,',')

newStr =

  8×1 cell array

    '106'
    '94'
    '241'
    '11'
    '190'
    '237'
    '209'
    '224'

>> cell2mat(newStr)
Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in cell2mat (line 83)
            m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});
```

This error is mind boggling. I am not trying to concatenate anything by running the cat function.

The '106' is actually seen by MATLAB is three separate ASCII characters. I just need to convert the cell array into a simple vector of numbers.

Comment: You want to convert the strings to numbers. You can do this with `str2mat` or `str2double`.

Comment: Why isn't there a str2int like str2double? It seems that I can use the str2double directly on the cell array. That is interesting,

Comment: Double is the core type in MATLAB, integers were tagged on later, and cannot be used in many places. You should use doubles for everything unless the reduced memory footprint of another type makes sense.

Comment: I see, I did know that double should be used by default. I assumed double is not required if we are only using whole numbers i.e integers.

Comment: It’s better to use doubles for everything, including integers and indexing, unless you’re worried about memory consumption. Integer arithmetic in MATLAB is … awkward.

Comment: I see, the only question that remains then is, when we do subtraction, we cannot expect the result to equal 0.0 when using doubles. This is just nature of how floating point maths works. How do you deal with that?

Comment: If the values you use are all integers smaller than 2^52, then arithmetic with them is exact. If you are unsure, use `round`.

Answer (score 1):

`cell2mat` can only convert `cell` array to `char` type, so if the elements in `cell` have different length, error will occur. Temporally, there is no good way to handle your problem, but you can use `for` loop.

```
for i = 1:length(newStr)
    num(i,1) = str2num(cell2mat(newStr(i)));
end
```

Apologize for my poor English.